# var directory showing its full via command 'df-h'

Tags: freebsd, disk-usage, var

df -h shows:

```
df -h
Filesystem     Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/ada0p2    1.9G    256M    1.5G    14%    /
devfs          1.0K    1.0K      0B   100%    /dev
/dev/ada0p4    804G     34G    706G     5%    /usr
/dev/ada0p5     93G    3.5G     82G     4%    /var
```

but, du -sh shows:

```
du -sh /var
3.5G    /var
```

Why? df is telling me i have no space out of the 93G but when i check the file size of the /var/ directory it amounts to 3.5G?

Can any one explain why this is please?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: that does not answer my question! However I will note that rule next time!

Comment: Don't confuse question comments with answers, and don't note the rule for next time.  [Edit] and fix _this_ question _now_, please.

Comment: removed images and pasted output.

Comment: Thank you.  Have you spotted that `df` is no longer doing what you said?  (-:  You actually have a more interesting question that is _not quite_ a duplicate of the other question, because you had `df` showing you that _even the free space reserved for the superuser_ had been taken (not the case in the other questions), and then showing you that it had come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your question is very interesting in itself the df and du tools work differently in Linux

according to Linux man page

```
du - estimate file space usage

df - report file system disk space usage
```

df works on the file system level while du works on file level so if there are  open file descriptors it will be reported by du but not df

Comment: Can you please upvote the answer as well thankyou